# How to hide panels when one bootstrap is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap panel . It has 3 panels . panel 1 , panel 2 , panel 3 . This panel is working fine normally .

**My logic :**

- When panel 1 click , it shows the content of panel 1  with both panel 2 , panel 3 should hide .
- When panel 2 click , it shows the content of panel 2 with both panel 1 , panel 3 should hide .
- When panel 3 click , it shows the content of panel 3 with both panel 1 , panel 2 should hide .

[image]

but i want to utilize the space also . That is the active panel should come first . so i can maintain the space also . ( All the active panel should come first position )

This is my existing code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Panel #1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
      panel 1 content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Panel #2 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        panel 2 content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Panel #3<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        panel 3 content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script :**

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-up").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
```

Any suggestion how can i done this with bootstrap collapse panel ?

Comment: I think you can't chnge the order of the panels with bootsrap alone. For this you would need some additional javascript to modify the order in which the panels are displayed

Comment: any sample scripts ?

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap collapse JS composant:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: ok . i can use . But how can i modify this for my scenario?

Comment: Isn't this the accordion instead of panels? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the active panel should come first position

In order to move at the first position the active tab a solution in jQuery is:

```
$('#accordion').prepend($(this).closest('div.panel-default'));
```

While moving at the first position you can save the current position of the panel so when you click again on the panel (the only visible) all the panels can be shown and the current panel can be positioned at the right place:

```
$(this).closest('div.panel-default')
       .insertAfter($('div.container div.panel-default').eq(idx))
```

So, the snippet is:

```js
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up");
  $(this).closest('div.panel-default').attr('idx', $(this).closest('div.panel-default').index());
  $('#accordion').prepend($(this).closest('div.panel-default'));
  $('div.container div.panel-default').not($(this).closest('div.panel-default')).hide();
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-up").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
});

$('#accordion a.accordion-toggle').on('click', function (e) {
  if ($('div.container div.panel-default:visible').not($(this).closest('div.panel-default')).length == 0) {
    var idx = $(this).closest('div.panel-default').attr('idx');
    $('div.container div.panel-default').show();
    $(this).closest('div.panel-default').insertAfter($('div.container div.panel-default').eq(idx))
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                        Panel #1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    panel 1 content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                        Panel #2 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    panel 2 content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                        Panel #3<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    panel 3 content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok this is working . how can i hide other Div boxes when i click on another ? means when i click panel 2 , panel 1 and panel 3 should hide . can i do this ? i don't want to see the other DIV boxes . only i want to see the active DIV box

Comment: @user2986042 Instead of prepend you may use hide. But how do you imagine to show again the hidden panel 2?

Comment: my aim : i want to move the clicked panel to top and don't want to display the other panels ( display: none ) . when i click again i want to see the first view (default view ) . can i do with div id's ?

Comment: @user2986042 Snippet updated. Could you test and let me know? Thanks so much